# pure.js must work with the existing page nodes?

Tags: javascript, templates, pure-js

```
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <script type='text/javascript' src="js/jquery/jquery-min.js"></script>
    <script type='text/javascript' src="js/pure/pure.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class='result'>Test Page</div>

    <script type='text/javascript'>
      $(document).ready(function(){
        var p;
        p = $("<div><ul><li></li></ul></div>");
        directives = {"li": "error"};
        data = {"error": "name must be between 3 and 250 characters long"};
        p.render(data, directives);
        $(".result").after(p);
        });
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

The above codes don't insert data into p object.But the following works,

```
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <script type='text/javascript' src="js/jquery/jquery-min.js"></script>
    <script type='text/javascript' src="js/pure/pure.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class='result'>Test Page</div>

    <script type='text/javascript'>
      $(document).ready(function(){
        var p;
        p = $("<div><ul><li></li></ul></div>");
        $(".result").after(p);
        directives = {"li": "error"};
        data = {"error": "name must be between 3 and 250 characters long"};
        p.render(data, directives);
        });
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

It seems to insert data, the jquery object(here,it is p)must manipulate the existing html tags? It is not reasonable like the latter,i want the first codes to insert data,but how?
Thanks, :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`render` returns always a node. And if the template is in the DOM, it is replaced with the rendered node.

You can do this:

```
p = p.render(data, directives);
$(".result").after(p);
```

or

```
$(".result").after( p.render(data, directives) );
```